# Releasing a connection in .NET HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am currently implementing an HTTP Handler that will take a POST of some XML data from some 3rd party, then will do some work with it. The processing that I will be doing with the XML has potential to take some time. Once I yank out the XML from the POST, there is no need to keep the connection open with the client while I process the data. As I don't have any control of when the client will time out posting to me, I just want to grab the XML and let the connection go.

Is there any easy way to go about this? Using the Response.Close() isn't correct, as it doesn't close the connection properly. Response.End() exits my HTTP Handler all together. I could throw the processing into a background thread, but I heard that can be a little risky in ASP.NET as the AppDomain can be torn down which could kill my process in the middle.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Using the Response.Close() isn't correct, as it doesn't close the connection properly" What error you are getting here?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx states: "This method terminates the connection to the client in an abrupt manner and is not intended for normal HTTP request processing. The method sends a reset packet to the client, which can cause response data that is buffered on the server, the client, or somewhere in between to be dropped." When I gave it a test, I got an HTTP error on the client

Comment: Correct, and to prevent that,we first close our stream and then we close the response.

Comment: @CodeSpread I have tried several combinations of closing the output stream, and the response, all still seem to receive an error such as (as viewed when requesting from chrome) Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data. If you have an example, I would love to give it a shot.

Comment: I have a link.check if it is useful http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input. The way I went about this, so others can ponder it as a solution:

The queuing would probably be the most "correct" means, but it would take some extra implementation that really is just over the top for what I am intending to do. Using the information from http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

First I  create my processing class and spin that up in a background thread to do the work after I get the XML from the client. This releases the connection while my worker thread continues in the background.

I registered my processing class as an `IRegisteredObject`. I the implemented the `Stop(bool immediate)` method

```
    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        if (!immediate && _working)
            return;//don't unregister yet, give it some time

        if(immediate && _working)
        {
            //TODO: Log this instance
        }
        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
```

I set my _working variable to true when I am processing work, and unset it when done. If in the rare case I am processing work and stop gets called because the AppDomain is getting taken down, it will first just return without unregistering itself. This gives my process a bit more time to finish up. If when the method gets called the second time with the immediate flag set to true, it quickly logs the issue and then unregister itself.

This may not be the ultimate solution, but for my purposes, this will take care of alerting me when the very rare condition happens, as well as not holding up the client's connection as I process the data.

Answer (score 2):

1. Save received data to some sort of permanent queue (MSMQ for example).
2. Exit handler.
3. Process data from queue in another application, for example in windows service.

This is not exactly "easy way", but safe and fast for customers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.5, check out [HttpTaskAsyncHandler](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097378).

From the linked page:

> Asynchronous HTTP handlers   The traditional approach to writing asynchronous handlers in ASP.NET is to implement the IHttpAsyncHandler
>   interface. ASP.NET 4.5 introduces the HttpTaskAsyncHandler
>   asynchronous base type that you can derive from, which makes it much
>   easier to write asynchronous handlers.   The HttpTaskAsyncHandler type
>   is abstract and requires you to override the ProcessRequestAsync
>   method. Internally ASP.NET takes care of integrating the return
>   signature (a Task object) of ProcessRequestAsync with the older
>   asynchronous programming model used by the ASP.NET pipeline.   The
>   following example shows how you can use Task and await as part of the
>   implementation of an asynchronous HTTP handler:

```
public class MyAsyncHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler 
{ 
        // ... 

        // ASP.NET automatically takes care of integrating the Task based override 
        // with the ASP.NET pipeline. 
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context) 
        { 
           WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
           var result = await  
                   wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.microsoft.com"); 
           // Do something with the result 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately I will be stuck on .NET 3.5. I did try a quick setup of an IHttpAsyncHandler using the simple tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.85).aspx. This doesn't seem to get what I want. The connection is still held open, but the thread is released to the thread pool to be re-used. From what I understand, it is for when you process many many requests and need to free up the processing threads

Comment: In that case, queueing up the work as in @Valtasarlll's answer below is what you'll need to do.